# Created new branch from existing commits, now origin and origin/master are out of sync

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a repo that I've been using with GitHub. Previously, the repo had only 1 branch (i.e. master) and was fully up-to-date with the remote repo, but having done 2 local commits of new experimental work, I decided that what I wanted to do was create a new branch with those 2 commits on a "dev" branch which would still be accessible on GitHub as an alternative branch.

Therefore, I did the following:

```
git branch dev             # create new branch
git reset --hard HEAD~2    # roll back 2 commits on HEAD
git checkout dev           # make dev the active branch
```

Locally, all is now good. I now have my two local branches: `master` (which is 2 commits behind -- on the stable version) and `dev (HEAD)` which is on the current experimental work.

However, on the GitHub side, all is not well: I have two branches, `master (HEAD)` and `dev`, however both of them are **exactly the same** (i.e. the two latest commits are on the `master`  branch, when actually I only want them on the `dev` branch).

So just to summarise, if we call the latest unstable commit (dev work), commit 10, and the stable commit number 8, then we have the following:

10 - `dev`, `origin/master`, `origin/dev`, `origin/HEAD`

9

8 - `master`

So the question is how I get `origin/master` to correctly point to commit 8. (And also I'm confused by the role of `origin/HEAD` in all of this...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the history of `master`, you need to `git push -f origin master` in order to make GitHub record the new HEAD for master. (Make sure to warn any collaborator of that change: they need to reset their local master branch to that new HEAD).
Pushing `dev` wasn't enough.

`origin/HEAD` reference the `HEAD` of the remote GitHub repo (which should be `origin/master`, unless you explicitly changed it through the GitHub repo Admin interface).